# Is it correct to say that Mongoose transforms its document object to JS object via .toJSON function?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

I am playing with MongoDB and Mongoose and found out that whenever I am using `console.log(user)` before `res.send` in the following code my password is not yet deleted. I want to know when Mongoose is calling `toJSON` object.

javascript

```
router.post('/user', valid, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = new User(req.body);

    await user.save();

    const token = await user.generateAuthToken();

    res.status(status.success).send({ ...successMessage, data: user, token });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(status.error).send({ errorMessage, e });
  }
});
```

The following code is the part of the user Schema file.

```js
userSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const user = this;

  console.log('Hello', user);

  const userObject = user.toObject();

  delete userObject.password;

  delete userObject.tokens;

  return userObject;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` function uses `util.format` to generate the string to output.  `util.format` calls [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) for any non-string value, which does not call toJSON.

You might try `console.log(JSON.stringify(user))` if you want toJSON to be called.

Comment: Actually, when I run that code sequence I am not getting when userSchema.methods.toJSON is called. I simply want to know the execution sequence.

Comment: According to the docs: `The return value of this method is used in calls to JSON.stringify(doc).`